# Object validation - How to validate [key: number]: string

Tags: typescript, validation, class-validator

I'm trying to write validator for `JSON` returned from Bugzilla API. When I'm fetching comments data, I'm getting something like this:

```sh
curl https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/comment/1
```

```json
{
    "comments": {
        "1": {...}
    },
    "bugs": {}
}
```

The number "1" refers to comment id, so typescript definition would be something like this:

```js
export interface Comment {
  comments: {
    [key: number]: CommentObject;
  };
  ...
}
```

My question is, is there way how to validate property names of objects? I checks `class-validator` and some others and to me it seems that all of those libraries are focusing only on validation of property values.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Property names of objects are either string or Symbols. If you want to validate your object, you need to check if its key is an integer-like string: i.e. attempt to convert the key into a number, and check if it is an integer.

Comment: I'm trying to propose this [PR](https://github.com/Mossop/bugzilla-ts/pull/41). The upstream is using own implementation of validators, but I'm not entirely sure how to extend functionality to validate `[key: number|string]: any`. [Upstream validators](https://github.com/Mossop/bugzilla-ts/blob/main/src/validators.ts), [Upstream types](https://github.com/Mossop/bugzilla-ts/blob/main/src/types.ts). Thanks Terry for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with help of Dave from bugzilla-ts

Solution can be found at: [Mossop/bugzilla-ts#41](https://github.com/Mossop/bugzilla-ts/pull/41/files#diff-a574d31e5e97028b4efc3b0c36bae71f00163d6d474231e2a41eaa352cf483a7R150-R167)